# TeamCity: push docker image to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, teamcity, amazon-ecr

Running `TeamCity 2019.1.4` with one server and three separate agents. Both agents and the server are running in their respective `server/agent` containers in separate EC2 instances. I want the build artifact (docker image) to be pushed to the ECR. Permission is configured via IAM role. I am getting `Unauthorized` error when pushing/pulling. Manually pulling image from the agent EC2 host works. But manually pulling from within the agent EC2 container gives the same error. How do I configure the TeamCity agent container to identify itself as the host machine?

PS: An option I am trying to avoid is to run TeamCity agents in a classic mode (manual installation) which will most likely work.

Comment: did you tired to login first before pull or push image? `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)`

Comment: there is no `aws` tool in the agent docker image.

Comment: you can find a solution in this [document](https://ngeor.com/2017/12/30/using-aws-ecr-as-a-docker-registry.html) about `teamcity` push to ecr repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do the following:

- in TeamCity project configuration, add ECR connection.
- then, in the build configuration, add build feature, add "Docker Support".
- make sure the choice "Log in to the Docker registry before the build"
  is checked and you choose the ECR connection from the project
  configuration.

Comment: But your not in luck if you want to log into several registries simultaneously. This does not seem to be supported.

Comment: Well, it does actually work with the latest TeamCity. I have got multiple ECR connections on a build config.

Comment: Interesting... I'll give it a try. For now I log into different registries manually.